# sort: stat failed: -: Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, pipe

I'm trying to implement a C program that emulates the following shell command line:

```
find . -type f -ls | cut -d " " -f 3- | sort -n -k 6 >file.txt ; less <file.txt
```

I'm quite new to processes, pipes and sockets and after trying several implementations and trying to look for solutions for the problem I am convinced I'm not yet skilled enough to understand the error on my own. 
Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here? when I try to execute the code I get the error:

```
sort: stat failed: -: Bad file descriptor.
```

Here's my child function associated with the sort command:

```
  // child 3 (sort)
  void child3(int *pipe_fd)
    {
    int fdo;

    // fecha parte do write do pipe
    if (close(pipe_fd[1]) == -1) erro("child 3-> failed to close pipe[1] (pipe_fd)");

    // alteração std_in ler do pipe
      if(dup2(pipe_fd[0], 0) == -1) erro("child 3 -> failed to dup2 (pipe_fd)" );

    // "fechar o file descriptor do pipe" pois já o redirecionamos
      if(close(pipe_fd[0]) == -1) erro("child 3 -> failed to close pipe[0]"); 

    // criação do file.txt com direitos de escrita e leitura
    if (fdo=open("file.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0600) == -1)
    erro("child_3 failed to open/create 'file.txt'");

    // redirecionamento do stdout para o sort
    if(dup2(fdo, 1) == -1)  erro("child 3 -> failed to dup2 (fdo)");        

    // fecho do file descriptor criado no open
    if(close(fdo) == -1 ) erro("child 3 -> failed to close pipe[1]");

    // executa o sort
      if (execlp("sort", "sort", "-n", "-k", "6",NULL) == -1) 
     erro("child_3 failed to execlp"); 

  }
```

Thanks in advance and I'm sorry if the post isn't correctly structured, it's my first post here. :)

Comment: Rather than dumping your entire program here for us to debug, it would be better to just provide a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulR I'm sorry I'll get on it

Comment: No problem - as a bonus you may well find that in the process of reducing this to a minimal example that you uncover your bug anyway! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is rather simple, and had you compiled with `gcc -Wall`, you'd have received a warning:

> ```
> warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
>        if (fdo=open("file.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0600) == -1) {
>        ^~
> ```

This suggests that an *assignment* expression to be parenthesized. And the correct bracketing should be

```
 if ((fdo = open("file.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0600)) == -1) {
```

Without parentheses, the precedence of `==` is higher than that of `=`, thus the expression is parsed as

```
  if (fdo = (open("file.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0600) == -1 )) {
```

Thus `fdo` will be set to `0` if `open` succeeded, and `1` if it failed. As it succeeded here, `fdo` will be `0` and the line

```
if (close(fdo) == -1)
```

will end up closing the descriptor `0` which was meant to be the standard *input* for `sort` and thus `sort` complains as `fstat(0, ...)` would return `EBADF`.

Comment: I can't believe it was such a silly error, I'll keep the flag in mind for further problems. Thank you so much for  your help! :)

Comment: @Aereth You couldn't see the bug because putting all that into the `if` statement's condition meant there was too much going on.  That's a really good reason for *never* putting assignments into a condition like that.  Two lines are *much* easier to *see* and understand:  `int fdo = open(...); if ( fdo == -1 )...` is a *lot* harder to mess up.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Indeed, I should be more patient with my code, I haven't been programing for long and there are still a lot of things I must get used to do in order to keep things organized and clean. Thank you very much for your insight, I'll take note so I try not to mess up in the future!